# Unique key on 2 columns over joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Hi i have 2 tables.

```
     A                              B
|-----|--------------|    |------|-------|--------|
| ID  |  aText       |    | ID   | aId   | bText  |
|-----|--------------|    |------|-------|--------|
| 1   |  test        |    | 10   |  1    |  zzzzz |
|-----|--------------|    |------|-------|--------|
```

Is it possible to create  a unique key on the bText combined with aText ?

aText and bText ain't unique in their serperataded tables.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: i want to make sure that i don't have any bText that are duplicated with the same aText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exactly no. You should use one table with parent

```
|------|-------|--------|
| ID   |Parent | Text   | 
|------|-------|--------|
| 1    |       | zzzzz  |
|------|-------|--------|
| 10   |   1   | yyyyy  |
-------------------------
```

Parent column foreign key to ID column its mean self refferencing.

Comment: Not really sure that's relevant here, you are making a lot of assumptions about the data structure.. and haven't really answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if `aText` is `UNIQUE` in table `A`; create a `UNIQUE INDEX` on `(aId,btext)` for table `B`

Otherwise I don't think it is possible with your current data structure.

Comment: aText ain't Unique in table A :/

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible, sorry, but I would suggest the problem lies with your data structure.. :(

Comment: Yeah, sadly i havn't done that my self and can't change it as it is :(

Comment: @Trind That is a shame.. just out of interest; Why have you accepted an answer that involves changing the data structure and doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @Trind Ah, the first two words! :)

Comment: Voted up your comments for all the help thou :)

Comment: Fair enough.. happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

yea you can create unique key for bText. but why you want to combine with aText . If you have id as unique key in both table and you can access any columns with a matching id constraints na by using where clause.

Comment: Maybe because you don't want bText to be unique, but you want the combination of aText and bText to be unique?